# C# remote connection in sql server 2008

Tags: c#

I Have one window project in c# that project is running in my computer very well way but i want to know how to run that project  on another computer without install visual studio and database 
how to do this do i need to install visual studio on another computer

Comment: You could compile your program and just run the binary on the target machine. When you want to run your program inside your studio you have to install a visual studio on the target machine.

Comment: when i run binary file on the target machine config file will be change

Answer (score 0):

yes you can

In most cases you should be able to simply copying your executable (found in that bin directory) to the target machine. There may also be a couple of other required / useful files in that folder that you might also want to copy (such as a .exe.config or .pdb file, or possibly even a .dll file if your program is split over multiple projects). If in doubt copying everything will probably work - at worst some of those files are just unneccessary (such as the .vshost files).

Your target machine will need to have the the .Net framework for the version that you are targetting (e.g. 2.0, 3.5, 4.0 etc...) installed. In many cases this will already be installed (especially so in the case of .Net 2.0), in the case that it isn't then generally these can be installed through Windows update, alternatively a quick search for ".Net version X installer" should do the trick. You should get a reasonably straightforward error messages if you try and run your application on machine that doesn't have the required .Net framework version installed

If you feel up to it then are extra things that you might want to do when distributing software to a client, such as

Building in Release mode
Creating an instaler
Deploying using

[Click](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t71a733d%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Comment: simply i want to ask i run my dll file of this project in another computer will the config file of that project be change or not if change what i should write in datasource my computer name or ip address

Comment: @sandeepkumar  http://erikej.blogspot.in/2011/02/using-sql-server-compact-40-with.html

Comment: Just take the outcomes of the bin folder, .exe and .dll files, make sure the other computer have required .net framework installed and you are good to go.